# Empty image when trying to change src in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am trying to change an image and some text in javascript trough a button.I can change the text but no matter what I do if I change the image it's just an image not found icon

Here's my relevant html:
`

```
<div class="review1">
      <img id="student" src="images\review1.png" />
      <div id="review1text">
        <h1 id="reviewnume">Alina,21</h1>
        <p id="reviewtext">
          Sunt studenta la Politehnica in Bucuresti si Pitagora.ro m-a ajutat
          foarte mult sa aprofundez cunostiintele mele de algebra.Recomand cu
          cea mai mare incredere!
        </p>
      </div>

     <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-left"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right"></i>
      
    </div>
```

`And here is my javascript:`

```
let btnNext = document.querySelector("fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right");
let btnprevious = document.querySelector("fa-solid.fa-circle-arrow-left");



btnNext = addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("reviewtext").textContent =
    "Nu am reusit sa ajung la cursurile mele de algebra din cause serviciului.In orice caz,nu a fost mare pierdere deoarece Pitagora.ro m-a ajutat sa recuperez materia fara probleme";
  document.getElementById("reviewnume").textContent = "Bogdan,22";
  document.getElementById("reviewnume").style.textAlign = "center";
  document.getElementById("reviewtext").style.fontSize = "25px";
  document.getElementById("reviewtext").style.marginLeft = "20px";
  document.getElementById("student").src = "images\review2.png";
});
```

Again,the text on "reviewnume" and "reviewtext" changes when I click but the image from "review1" to "review2" doesn't,even though they are in the same folder

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: `"images\review2.png"` -> `"\r"` is a carriage return in JS, either write `"images\\review2.png"` or `"images/review2.png"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you forgot to use the `dot(.)` operator when finding an element using a class name.

I mean, you did-

```
let btnNext = document.querySelector("fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right");
```

But you should do-

```
let btnNext = document.querySelector(".fa-solid .fa-circle-arrow-right");
or
let btnNext = document.querySelector(".fa-circle-arrow-right");
```

You also used the wrong syntax for the event listener.

```
btnNext = addEventListener("click", () => {...});
```

but it should be-

```
btnNext.addEventListener("click", () => {...});
```

Here is the working demo-

```js
let btnNext = document.querySelector(".fa-circle-arrow-right");
let btnprevious = document.querySelector(".fa-circle-arrow-left");


btnNext.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("reviewtext").textContent =
    "Nu am reusit sa ajung la cursurile mele de algebra din cause serviciului.In orice caz,nu a fost mare pierdere deoarece Pitagora.ro m-a ajutat sa recuperez materia fara probleme";
  document.getElementById("reviewnume").textContent = "Bogdan,22";
  document.getElementById("reviewnume").style.textAlign = "center";
  document.getElementById("reviewtext").style.fontSize = "25px";
  document.getElementById("reviewtext").style.marginLeft = "20px";
  document.getElementById("student").src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300";
});

btnprevious.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("student").src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="review1">
      <img id="student" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
      <div id="review1text">
        <h1 id="reviewnume">Alina,21</h1>
        <p id="reviewtext">
          Sunt studenta la Politehnica in Bucuresti si Pitagora.ro m-a ajutat
          foarte mult sa aprofundez cunostiintele mele de algebra.Recomand cu
          cea mai mare incredere!
        </p>
      </div>

     <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-left"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right"></i>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
const image = document.getElementById("student");

image.setAttribute("src","images\review2.png");
```

If it doesn't work check the path or the type of image is png or not.

Answer (score -1):

change
document.getElementById("student").src = "images\review2.png";
to

document.getElementById("student").setAttribute('src', "images\review2.png");